# Suggested Edit was MUCH longer than original answer

Tags: discussion, answers

So I ran across an answer to a question that was not much more than a couple of short sentences and the suggested edit was six paragraphs plus three images:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/333809

Hopefully that link works and shows the specific edit I was concerned about.

The edit feels like it just should have been a separate answer and not an edit of an existing one. Problem is I have no idea what you do in a situation like this. I skipped voting on the edit, but it kinda felt like that is something that should have been brought to a Mod's attention (but no way to do that), or am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 3):

The user editing the answer left a comment as well, about them not being able to post an answer on their own because the question is protected and they don‘t have enough reputation. So yes, a separate answer would maybe have been better, but having the additional information on the site at all has a lot of value (and the edit improved a rather short answer as well)

Comment: Hmmmmm that comment wasn't there when I saw the answer, or missed it. But thx for the clarity!